# VS code: не удается выполнить запись в файл параметров пользователя

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, settings

При смене темы в VS code возникает блок с текстом:

> Не удалось выполнить запись в параметры пользователя, поскольку в этом файле есть несохраненные изменения. Сохраните файл параметров пользователя, затем повторите попытку.

И кнопка выводящая на settings.json с ошибкой в `"code-runner.executorMap"` (неизвестный параметр конфигурации).

**Проблема:**

```
Expected comma jsonc(514) [6, 5]
```

**settings.json:**

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "javascript": "node",
        "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "php": "php",
        "python": "python -u",
        "perl": "perl",
        "perl6": "perl6",
        "ruby": "ruby",
        "go": "go run",
        "lua": "lua",
        "groovy": "groovy",
        "powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
        "bat": "cmd /c",
        "shellscript": "bash",
        "fsharp": "fsi",
        "csharp": "cd $dir && dotnet run $fileName",
        "vbscript": "cscript //Nologo",
        "typescript": "ts-node",
        "coffeescript": "coffee",
        "scala": "scala",
        "swift": "swift",
        "julia": "julia",
        "crystal": "crystal",
        "ocaml": "ocaml",
        "r": "Rscript",
        "applescript": "osascript",
        "clojure": "lein exec",
        "haxe": "haxe --cwd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash --run $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "rust": "cd $dir && rustc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "racket": "racket",
        "scheme": "csi -script",
        "ahk": "autohotkey",
        "autoit": "autoit3",
        "dart": "dart",
        "pascal": "cd $dir && fpc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "d": "cd $dir && dmd $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "haskell": "runhaskell",
        "nim": "nim compile --verbosity:0 --hints:off --run",
        "lisp": "sbcl --script",
        "kit": "kitc --run",
        "v": "v run",
        "sass": "sass --style expanded",
        "scss": "scss --style expanded",
        "less": "cd $dir && lessc $fileName $fileNameWithoutExt.css",
        "FortranFreeForm": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran-modern": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran_fixed-form": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Элементы json должны быть разделены запятыми. В строке `"code-runner.runInTerminal": true` нужно добавить запятую в конце. При открытии такого файла в vscode вам должно подчеркнуть следующую строку и при наведении показать ошибку "Expected comma". Эта ошибка буквально означает, что не хватает запятой.

Comment: Благодарствую!!!

Comment: Добавь свой комментарий, как ответ, я его правильным отмечу.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ основан на [комментарии @insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1370024/vs-code-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f/1438839#comment2431995_1370024).

Элементы json должны быть разделены запятыми. В строке "code-runner.runInTerminal": true нужно добавить запятую в конце. При открытии такого файла в vscode вам должно подчеркнуть следующую строку и при наведении показать ошибку "Expected comma". Эта ошибка буквально означает, что не хватает запятой.